# When moving rows via script through data validation, it's sometimes taking the below row with it when it shouldn't be

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

So I've come across a problem that looks either glitchy or just errorful and would greatly appreciate a solution or any feedback!

It's for a holiday sheet. In column A you have a name, in Column B you have a start date, and in Column C you have an end date. To enable managers to approve or decline holiday, there's a fourth column, where a data validation lives. The options in the data validation are 'Approved' or 'Declined'. When approved, the holiday goes into the 'Approved' tab to be taken to the calendar by another script. If declined it goes into the declined tab and notifies the requester that the holiday has been declined. If left blank it just stays in that neutral sheet.

However, the problem is when the manager approves the holiday, sometimes the script **takes the below row with it when moving to either 'Approved' or 'Declined' tabs and it's causing a lot of confusion**. Luckily the automation based on the 'Approved' sheet only moves the holiday to the calendar when the fourth column has 'approved' written in it. But I really need to fix and I'm not sure how to.

The script I'm using to move the row to a tab is:

```
   function onEdit(event) {
  // assumes source data in sheet named main
  // target sheet of move to named Completed
  // getColumn with check-boxes is currently set to column 4 or D
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

  if(s.getName() == "Submitted" && r.getColumn() == 11 && r.getValue() == "Approved") {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Approved");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
  } else if(s.getName() == "Submitted" && r.getColumn() == 11 && r.getValue() == "Declined") {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Declined");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
  }
}
```

This script was seen in https://support.google.com/docs/thread/24467278?hl=en but I bastardized it slightly to suit the validation.

Any help would be really absolutely awesome! I've been looking for a while in Stack and in Reddit and in the google forums and can't really find anything that relates to the issue.

Comment: Nothing in the script seems to be related to your problem. Is it possible you misunderstood the issue?

Comment: Can you provide a copy of the sheet to try to reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that it isn't in fact taking multiple rows at the same time, but taking the wrong row, then after another edit the right row?

I suspect that that happens when someone uses the keyboard instead of the mouse to select Approved (not because the hardware matters, but the selection method can be different). Your code is looking for the active range to determine the row. So if I move to the cell where I would select Approved, and then type a and press enter, the active row when the script runs would be the row below (pressing enter moves the selection to the cell below).  Should be easy enough to test this.